# Why hyphen(-) behaves peculiarly in python strings?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I found a peculiar behavior while going through Python 3 data types especially **string**. If two strings `a`  and `b` have the same value then `a is b` becomes `True` (Strings must not contain **hyphen** of course).

If:

```
>>> a = 'string_without_hyphen'
>>> b = 'string_without_hyphen'
```

Then:

```
>>> a is b
True
>>> a == b
True
```

But if:

```
>>> a = 'string-with-hyphen'
>>> b = 'string-with-hyphen'
```

Then,

```
>>> a is b
False
>>> a == b
True
```

which confused me.

Why is this happening?

Comment: If you do your code the other way round, i.e. start out with hypens and then change to underscores, does the behaviour happen in the same order or follow the hyphens?

Comment: correct me if i am wrong but i think the ascii value for both the chars are diff

Comment: Should that last line, `>>> b == b` be `>>> a == b` instead?

Comment: yes, it should be a == b

Answer (score 6):

Because <del>moon rays and unicorns</del> implementation details.

The `is` operator compares objects by identity, not by content.

The Python implementation you're using may or may not decide to reuse the same string object for both `a` and `b`, if it feels like it, since strings are immutable in Python. The same may or may not occur for integers (and in fact, this also happens with Java's `Integer`s if they're sufficiently small).

The gist is: never use `is` unless you really do need identity (address) comparison; things may be weird. Use `==` instead.

Comment: See the dup I found. This happens because the code executed in the REPL.

Comment: @DeepSpace Er, the accepted answer in the duplicate says this is caused by the string being a name string, not by REPL use.

Comment: As you said, implementation details. I suppose the rules for string interning are not set in stone. See for yourself: Compare the output of `a = 'string-with-hyphen' ; b = 'string-with-hyphen' ; print(a is b)` when it is executed "at once" from a py file, and when it is executed line by line in a REPL